# Несколько вопросов про Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

1. Поддерживает ли они подготовку запроса или каждый запрос компилируется по новой?
2. Я правильно понимаю, что если соединение закрыто, то он его открывает на время выполнения запроса, а потом закрывает? Если соединение изначально открыто, то оно поддерживается, пока я сам его не закрою?
3. В Dapper можно делать такое `Execute("INSERT INTO Table(f1,f2) values(@f1,@f2)",List)`
   где List- это список из нескольких объектов для вставки. Он будет по 1 записи вставлять или генерировать запросы из N строк List'a и вставлять?

Comment: 2) он вообще не управляет соединением. Это всего лишь методы расширения к инстансу коннекта.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Компиляцией запросов занимается БД. Если говорить о подготовке, то нет, [Даппер не подготавливает запросы](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/474). Однако есть некоторый внутренний кэш, который позволяет быстрее материализовывать объекты. При этом если вы используете параметры и выполняете один и тот же запрос много раз, кэш это учтет.

   > Dapper caches information about every query it runs, this allow it to
   >   materialize objects quickly and process parameters quickly.
2. Как верно отметил @vitidev, Даппер предоставляет методы расширения для соединения. Раньше он действительно не занимался управлением состояния соединения и требовал открытого соединения. Однако сейчас он открывает закрытые соединения ([раз](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/61e965eed900355e0dbd27771d6469248d798293/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs#L239), [два](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/61e965eed900355e0dbd27771d6469248d798293/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L935)) и, соответственно, закрывает их. При этом ему по-прежнему можно передавать открытое соединение и документация ко многим методам до сих пор гласит, что требуется открытое соединение.
3. [Да, можно](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#execute-a-command-multiple-times). Насчет того, как именно выполняется такая операция, не скажу. Надо или читать исходники, или пробовать и смотреть в профайлере. (Если вдруг нужно использовать bulk insert, есть дополнение [Dapper Plus](http://dapper-plus.net).)

   ```
   connection.Execute(@"insert MyTable(colA, colB) values (@a, @b)",
       new[] { new { a=1, b=1 }, new { a=2, b=2 }, new { a=3, b=3 } }
   ).IsEqualTo(3); // 3 rows inserted: "1,1", "2,2" and "3,3"
   ```

Comment: Я 3 вопрос добавил, на него не ответите дополнительно?

Comment: @iluxa1810 обновил ответ.